# Clear remaining cells when value is added

Tags: excel, vba, range

In Excel I have a Table with about 8 products(8 rows).
(the table is a drop down list and can be sorted on alphabet)
The table auto expands when a new product is added at the bottom of the list.

The table is set up like explained below:

Column B = Product Number

Column C = Product Name

Column D = Certain Value

Column E = Certain Value

Column D and E are Usually empty, I want only 1 cell in the whole range(D1:E8) to contain any value. If a new value is added, all the other Cell's in this range need to be cleared.

Is This possible by using a VBA Macro? (If so... Then how?)

For Example,

D3= "x". When a string "x" is entered in cell E6, all other cells (including D3 need to become empty).  I'd like to do this by starting a VBA macro, so I could add some additional actions that need to happen after one of the products is selected with an "x"in Column D or E. I know this can be done by a userform as well, but would prefer to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Worksheet module of the sheet you want this to affect use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D1:E8")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please edit one cell at a time!"
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        newVal = Target.Value
        Range("D1:E8").ClearContents
        Target.Value = newVal

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like a very clever sollution! Thanks a lot so far. Unfortunatley it doesn't seem to work(or run). When entering multiple values in different cells within the range it doesn't delete te previous enterys when entering new values in other cells within the range. Does it ''auto run'' when new values are entered, or do I require to start/active te code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you've put the code in a standard code module instead of the sheet module... I've also added a couple of extra 'safety' checks in the code